# Fade-in turns whole video stream to black

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-editing

I've adapted the [following crossfade from Gyan](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/17504/23109) to create a video from an image and an audio file, and then crossfade it with an outro. This works fine, but I also want to have the first video stream fade-in.

Using the `fade` filter to do this simply turns the whole of the stream black for reasons that I can't comprehend:

```
ffmpeg -i "image.jpg" -i "audio.flac" -i "outro.mp4" \
-movflags faststart \
-filter_complex \
"color=black:1384x1080:d=186.367[base]; \
[0:v]fade=in:st=0:d=2,scale=1384:1080,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
[2:v]format=yuva420p,fade=in:st=0:d=2:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+((168)/TB)[v1]; \
[base][v0]overlay[tmp]; \
[tmp][v1]overlay,format=yuv420p[fv]; \
[1:a][2:a]acrossfade=d=2[fa]" \
-map [fv] -map [fa] -map -0:v:1 -c:v libx264 -c:a libopus -shortest "track1.mp4"
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An image input is treated as a video stream consisting of one frame. To carry out a fade, you need multiple frames, at least as long as the duration of the fade.

For a 2-second fade-in, change

```
-i "image.jpg"
```

to

```
-loop 1 -t 2 -i "image.jpg"
```

Comment: Exactly what was needed, thank you.